# How to write jq script to extract elements that might appear as singleton or list?

Tags: json, jq, conditional-operator

How can one write a jq query that will extract a property from an element that may appear as singleton or list?

For example, extract the URL property from the creator in both example JSON strings below.

**Example #1:**

```
{
"@type": "example1",
"creator":{
   "@type":"Organization",
   "url": "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/"
 }
}
```

**Example #2:**

```
{ 
 "@type": "example2",
 "creator": [{
    "@type":"Person",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/homepage"
},
{
 "url": "https://www.example.com/another"
 }]
}
```

I have tried using `.creator` for the first one and `.creator[]` for the second one, but these two are not compatible. Is there a way to write so that it works for both examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility that is very straightforward is simply to test whether .creator is an array or not:

```
if .creator|type == "array" then .creator[] else .creator end
| .url
```

#### Streaming parser

At the other end of the spectrum of straightforwardness, here is another possibility that would be relevant if (a) the input JSON document was ginormous, and (b) the goal is to list all .url values that occur as immediate children of .creator, no matter where the keys are located in the input JSON document.  The invocation would use the **--stream** command-line option, e.g.

```
 jq --stream -f filter.jq input.json
```

The jq filter in this case is:

```
select(length==2 and 
       (.[0][-1] == "url") and
       last( .[0][:-1][]| strings ) == "creator")
| .[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!